# How to get Azure File Share to work with Wordpress multisite domain mapping when file share mounted to wp-content to resolve eorror 520

Tags: virtual-machines, wordpress, azure-storage, wordpress-mu

I am getting an error 520 on my images from sub-sites that domain mapped in wordpress. I am running azure file share with an azure vm that I plan to expand to more vm's. The File share is mounted to the wp-content blogs.dir folder. If I move the images off the file share to the server everything works fine, but if I remount the file share then the images and content stored  on the file share is inaccessible to the sub-sites, they are blocked from loading. This leads me to believe its a cross domain issue with Azure File Share, or an issue with the file share handling the mod rewrite, but that is all I have so far. I can't figure out how to resolve.

My goal is to setup a scalable server hosting wordpress that I can connect other servers to for load balancing. So the file share would grant site content no matter the server the user connects to.

The main domain works fine (originaldomain.com) as well the original wordpress domains unmapped (i.e. networkname.originaldomain.com/subsite/), if I access the subsites through their original domains the images load and there are no errors. This only happens with a mapped domain (newdomain.com) and when the blogs.dir (running a multi-network) is mounted to the fileshare.

Please help